# await for another method

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I think I need async await for my program but I can't figure out how to do it. From GetData method I need send request to socket, and finally get socket data to same method. Need to pass data somehow from OnReceive to initial GetData method. Is it possible to implement await async tasks here?  Here is simplified scheme:

```
AsyncCallback m_pfnLookupCallback;
    Socket m_sock;

    public void GetData()
    {
        string data;
        if (condition) data = GetDataFromCache();
        else data = GetDataFromNet(); /// !NEED AWAIT FOR SOCKET DATA HERE

        //will process data here.

    }

    public string GetDataFromNet()
    {
        m_sock.Send(szCommand, iBytesToSend, SocketFlags.None);
        WaitForData("s1");
    }
    public void WaitForData(string sSocketName)
    {
            m_pfnLookupCallback = new AsyncCallback(OnReceive);
            m_sock.BeginReceive(m_szLookupSocketBuffer, 0, m_szLookupSocketBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, m_pfnLookupCallback, sSocketName);
    }

    private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        int iReceivedBytes = 0;
        iReceivedBytes = m_sockLookup.EndReceive(asyn);
        string sData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(m_szLookupSocketBuffer, 0, iReceivedBytes); //WHAT I NEED
    }
```

p.s. I would avoid changing socket work if possible because they are used in other parts of program.

Comment: You can always wrap code that takes long time to finish in Task.Run and await that..

Comment: you should never do that.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx @Filip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn the old IAsyncResult pattern (APM) into async await quite easily. Here's an example of the socket call:

```
var byteCount = await Task.Factory.FromAsync(
    (callback, s) =>
    {
        return clientSocket.BeginReceive(
            m_szLookupSocketBuffer, 
            0, 
            cm_szLookupSocketBuffer.Length,
            SocketFlags.None, 
            callback,
            sSocketName);
    },
    result => clientSocket.EndReceive(result),
    null);
```